# How to count rows that share a unique field in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Imagine I have a dataframe that stores the books that individual people have read and their scores for them:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'person' : [1,1,2,2,3,3], 
'book' : ['dracula', 'frankenstein', 'dracula', 'frankenstein',   'dracula', 'rebecca'], 
'score':[10,11,12,13,14,15]
})

df

           book  person  score
0       dracula       1     10
1  frankenstein       1     11
2       dracula       2     12
3  frankenstein       2     13
4       dracula       3     14
5       rebecca       3     15
```

What I want to get is a dataframe showing for each pair of books how many people have read them both i.e. the desired outcome looks like this:

```
               dracula    frankensten   rebecca
dracula          3             2           1
frankenstein     2             2           0
rebecca          1             0           1
```

I.e. there are two people who have read both `dracula` and `frankenstein`, one person who has read both `dracula` and `rebecca`, etc. I don't care about the scores.

I have a feeling this has something to do with pivot/stack/unstack, but can't figure it out, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.book, df.person)
print (df.dot(df.T))
book          dracula  frankenstein  rebecca
book                                        
dracula             3             2        1
frankenstein        2             2        0
rebecca             1             0        1
```

Or solution with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['book','person'])['person'].size().unstack().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df.dot(df.T))
book          dracula  frankenstein  rebecca
book                                        
dracula             3             2        1
frankenstein        2             2        0
rebecca             1             0        1
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for providing the two solutions - I find the `groupby` one more familiar, but obviously this is exactly the type of problem that `crosstab` is for, so I will endeavour to learn it.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a pivot table and multiply it with its transpose:

```
pvt = pd.pivot_table(df, index='book',  columns='person', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0)
pvt.dot(pvt.T)
Out: 
book          dracula  frankenstein  rebecca
book                                        
dracula             3             2        1
frankenstein        2             2        0
rebecca             1             0        1
```